# Connect android with php mySQL

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, nullpointerexception

i am kind a new in android programming. I am trying to create an app that will communicate with a database on the internet. As a help i am using an project from [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). 
For begining i want to create app that will send some data to the db on localhost. I am using WAMP.

After running my app, and inserting data that i want to store on db, i'm getting bunch of exceptions and my application crashes.
For example:

1. E/Buffer Error(545): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
2. E/JSON Parser(545): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
3. E/AndroidRuntime(545): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
4. E/AndroidRuntime(545): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

And a lot of others exceptions...

My php scripts (or whatever you want to call them) are working fine, but I guess that problem is somewhere in JSONParser or other android activity... I've been searching for the solution but i couldn't find it, or i couldn't understand it. Also, i have downloaded code from androidhive, and it didn't work on my computer. Similar problem as with my project

Activity for creating order (product or whatever):

```
package com.example.heywaiter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NewProductActivity extends Activity{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputTablle;
EditText inputOrder;
EditText inputQuantity;
Button btnOrder;

private static String url_create_product = "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/create_product.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_product);

    inputTablle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputTablle);
    inputOrder = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputOrder);
    inputQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputQuantity);
    btnOrder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOrder);

    btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}
```

Inner class:

```
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Sending order...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String tablle = inputTablle.getText().toString();
        String drink = inputOrder.getText().toString();
        String quantity = inputQuantity.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tablle", tablle));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("drink", drink));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", quantity));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params);

        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        try{

            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if(success ==1){
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            }else{

            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

JSONParser

```
package com.example.heywaiter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {


static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }          


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

 }
}
```

Also if you need my androidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.heywaiter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.heywaiter.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.heywaiter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.heywaiter.MainActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".NewProductActivity"
            android:label="New Product">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AllProductsActivity"
            android:label="All Products" >
        </activity>
    </application>
    <!--  Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time for me to find where is the problem and I cannot believe what was it..

**When connecting to the localhost instead of:**

```
private static String url_create_product = "http://127.0.0.1/android_connect/create_product.php";
```

**in the NewProductActivity.java class the following code should be used:**

```
private static String url_all_products = "https://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_product.php";
```

For some reason you cannot use **127.0.0.1** but with **10.0.2.2** everything will be just fine.

Answer (score -1):

use that for save to database

```
nameValuePairs2 = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
try{
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(mainurl+"registration.php");
  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
  //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }catch(Exception e){
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//   System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
```